# Coffeescript, how would I write this queued functions example, especially the looping?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm trying to get some examples under my belt of how you would do something differently in CoffeeScript to JavaScript. In this example of queuing functions I'm confused at how you would do handle this in CoffeeScript

```
    wrapFunction = (fn, context, params) ->
            return ->
                fn.apply(context, params)        

    sayStuff = (str) ->
        alert(str)


    fun1 = wrapFunction(sayStuff, this, ['Hello Fun1'])
    fun2 = wrapFunction(sayStuff, this, ['Hello Fun2'])

    funqueue = []
    funqueue.push(fun1)
    funqueue.push(fun2)

    while (funqueue.length > 0) {
        (funqueue.shift())();   
    }
```

Especially how would I rewrite this in CoffeeScript?

```
while (Array.length > 0) {
    (Array.shift())();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f1 = (completeCallback) ->
  console.log('Waiting...')
  completeCallback()

funcs = [ f1, f2, f3 ]

next = ->
  if funcs.length > 0
    k = funcs.shift()
    k(next)

next()
```

Comment: So I just need to write a completeCallback function?

Comment: Edited. `next` passes itself as an argument into each queued function. Each queued function should make sure to call the argument passed into it (here, the formal parameter name in `f1` was `completeCallback`) in order to cause the next queued function to be invoked.

Comment: This is necessary because `f1` can set up an AJAX call and return immediately. Meanwhile, it passes into the AJAX call a `success` handler function which the browser will invoke at some later point. The functions queue needs to be held up until the success handler function is invoked and completes as well, not just until `f1` has returned (this is per your description of the problem).

Comment: Meh, this doesn't work as a sequential callback either. Sorry

Answer (score 4):

```
fun1 = -> alert 'Hello Fun1'
fun2 = -> alert 'Hello Fun2'

funqueue = [fun1, fun2]

el() for el in funqueue
```

Comment: Stunningly simpler syntax. However how would I make the functions only fire when the previous one had finished?

Comment: Are you asking how to use CoffeeScript or how to write a concurrent queue?

Comment: This example is sequential - CoffeeScript looping over an array is sequential, not parallel, so each function in the queue will have to return before the CoffeeScript loop will call the next one.

Comment: I'm not asking how to write a concurrent queue. I'm asking how to write a sequential queue (a queue where each function only fires upon the completion of the previous. The alerts is a bad example. But say the functions were animations that did something for 5 seconds and I wanted to fire them so that function fun2 only fired when fun1 had completed. AND I'm looking for the CoffeeScript way of doing this!